# Obtain new polygon outline from 2 intersected polygons?

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection

[image]

There are 2 polygons intersected. I can get a intersected small polygon by using "ST_INTERSECTION(geom, geom)". But I want to outer join the polygons like the uploaded image.

Comment: Add tag so we know what GIS software you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you are using PostGIS given that you are using `ST_Intersection()`. Try looking into `ST_Union()`, which should achieve what you want.

See [here](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) and [here](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geometry_returning.html) for more information.